# What went wrong in this u-substitution in integrating functions in terms of sine?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

So let's say there's this thing I want to integrate in terms of sine:

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\sin{x}}\,dx$$

Since the integrand is apparently invariant when we map $x$ to $\pi-x$, we could try setting $x = \pi-u$, and consequently $u=\pi-x$, and see what happens:
$$\frac{du}{dx}=-1$$
$$I=\int \frac{1}{1+\sin{x}}\,dx=\int \frac{1}{1+\sin{\pi-u}}\,dx \cdot\frac{-du}{dx}$$
$$=\int\frac{-1}{1+\sin{u}}\,du=-\int\frac{1}{1+\sin{u}}\,du=-I$$

Since $I=-I$, we conclude that $I=0$, so the integral is $0$.

Well, clearly this is garbage.  I don't do much calculus, so clearly there's a concept I'm terribly misinterpreting here.  Where's the error?  Should I go to sleep?  Did I eat something bad?

Comment: you should take into account the integral domain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're treating $I$ as if it were a number. Are you doing a definite integral, say, from $a$ to $b$? Then you have
$$\int_a^b \frac{dx}{1+\sin x} = -\int_{\pi-a}^{\pi-b} \frac{du}{1+\sin u}.$$
This doesn't look like $I=-I$ to me.

Comment: Why does it not work if we treat this as an indefinite integral and manipulating $I$ as a function?

Comment: First, you're comparing a function of $x$ and a function of $u=\pi-x$. Second, don't forget that antiderivatives are only defined up to a constant. So $F(x)=-F(\pi-x)+C$ is what you have.

Comment: Basically, an indefinite integral is a function of the bound variable (plus an arbitrary constant), so when you substitute $x\gets\pi-u$ you have *defined* $u$ in terms of $x$ and so *cannot* substitute $u\gets x$ . The back substitution *must* be $u\gets\pi-x$ $$\left.{\displaystyle\int \dfrac{\mathsf d s}{1+\sin s}}\right\lvert_{s=x}=-\left.{\displaystyle\int \dfrac{\mathsf d s}{1+\sin s}}\right\lvert_{s=\pi-x}\color{silver}{+C}$$

Comment: For me the issue here is that if $a \lt b$ then $\pi-a \gt \pi-b$ so you actually have $\int_a^b \frac{dx}{1+\sin x} = +\int_{\pi-b}^{\pi-a} \frac{du}{1+\sin u}$

Comment: @Henry, yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try $u$ substitution.

Take $u=\tan\left(\dfrac x2\right)$ and continue $\int\dfrac{2}{u^2+2u+1}du$

Comment: It's actually way easier than that. Multiply and divide by $1-\sin x$.

Comment: Yes, you are right but anyway either of the ways work.

Comment: This would be a good answer to the question "how do I solve this integral". Alas, a different question was asked.